# "Meilleur" or "mieux" for "It will be better"

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes

> (a) Aujourd'hui il pleut beaucoup. J'espère que demain il sera ____.

Should "meilleur" or "mieux" be used here? I suspect "meilleur" because an adjective is needed to describe the (unspecified) subject "il".

Does the answer change if we change "sera" to "fera"?

> (b) Aujourd'hui il pleut beaucoup. J'espère que demain il **f**era ____.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither option can fit your first sentence. You have to modify it like:

> J'espère que demain le temps sera meilleur.

Only the b sentence is correct, with "meilleur", as you guessed:

> J'espère que demain il fera meilleur.

Any other option would sound very odd to a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Rapport, comparaison relative :

> (a) Aujourd'hui il pleut beaucoup. J'espère que demain *sera mieux* qu'aujourd'hui.

Rapport, comparaison absolue  :

> (b) Aujourd'hui il pleut beaucoup. J'espère que demain il *fera meilleur* temps.

Souvent à l'oral ou dans des conversation familières , on peut employer l'un ou l'autre :

> ... J'espère que demain sera *mieux/meilleur*.