# Utiliser mieux/meilleur bien/bon avec être

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes

Which sentence is better?

```
"Quelle phrase est meilleure?"
```

or

```
"Quelle phrase est mieux?"
```

[image: Google translate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to say it would be :

> *Quelle phrase est **la** meilleure ?*

Using ***mieux*** (an adverb) instead of ***meilleur*** (an adjective) is possible but usually more colloquial.

See also:

["Meilleur" or "mieux" for "It will be better"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19730)
[Quelle est la différence entre meilleur et mieux ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6431)
[Using "mieux" to compare two nouns](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22286)
[Je suis mieux, je suis meilleur](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43441)

Comment: Donc, c'est `"Quelle phrase est la meilleure ?"` qui est la meilleure?

Comment: Would this compare to the difference "which sentence is better" versus "which sentence is the best" and "which sentence is best"? Is the meaning between "meilleur" and "la meilleure" different?

Comment: *Quelle phrase est meilleure ?* is fine, *Quelle phrase est mieux ?* is colloquial, spoken French.

Comment: *Meilleur* means "**more *bon***" and qualify something/someone while *mieux* means "**more *bien***" and apply to a verb.

Comment: that's right: *la meilleure* means "the best (one)".

Answer (score -1):

The first one : "Quelle phrase est meilleure?". In fact, "phrase" has a feminine gender, so you'll say : "meilleure". "Mieux" is used for male nouns.

Comment: Not at all. e.g. : *C'est elle la mieux*. Also, there are no "male nouns", only masculine ones.

Comment: No one says "C'est elle la mieux".  We all say "meilleure" when we compare a non masculine thing to something

Comment: I have heard and said enough times *C'est elle la mieux* to disagree. Moreover we say *C'est elle la mieux habillée*, not *C'est elle la "meilleure habillée"*.

Comment: @Silentobserver "Ce cheval est le meilleur" and "Cette voiture est la meilleure". But what does mieux have to do with masculine/feminine? It's about determinate versus indeterminate.

Comment: I don't like to downvote newcomers, but this answer is factually false dans misleading.